# Set a value comparer in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, dbcontext, data-conversion, jsonconverter, entity-framework-core-3.1

I have used "HasConversion" in my DBContext to define a JSonArray (Language/Value) and save it as a Text field for ages and It works like a charm, I added a new project to my solution, nothing changed but then I got a new error on adding migration regarding "setting a value comparer".

My **Model** is like:

```
    public class Brand
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public new IList<LangValue> Name { get; set; } = new List<LangValue>();
    }
```

and **DBContext** is like:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<Brand>(t =>
    {

        t.Property(p => p.Name).HasConversion(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include}),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<LangValue>>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Include})
         );
    });
```

It was working perfectly, but after adding a new project I got Yellow error in adding migration and Model does not add to the new database.

**Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Model.Validation[10620]
      The property 'Name' on entity type 'Brand' is a collection or enumeration type with a value converter but with no value comparer. Set a value comparer to ensure the collection/enumeration elements are compared correctly.**

Answer (score 31):

The explanation from ValueComparer docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-comparers#mutable-classes

A typical value conversion on a list property might convert the list to and from JSON:

```cs
modelBuilder
    .Entity<EntityType>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .HasConversion(
        v => JsonSerializer.Serialize(v, null),
        v => JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<int>>(v, null));
```

This then requires setting a `ValueComparer<T>` on the property to force EF Core use correct comparisons with this conversion:

```cs
var valueComparer = new ValueComparer<List<int>>(
    (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
    c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
    c => c.ToList());

modelBuilder
    .Entity<EntityType>()
    .Property(e => e.MyProperty)
    .Metadata
    .SetValueComparer(valueComparer);
```

### .NET 7+ update

You should consider using records instead of classes. They have comparison operator defined automatically and work perfectly with EF.

Comment: Are you saying that there's no need to use `HasConversion`? I see you put in `SetValueComparer` and passed a defined `valueComparer` but I see no connection to the  `HasConvertion` receiving `converter` (OP has it anonymously passed). I usually have `new ValueConverter<T,U>(a => a.ToU(),b => b.ToT())`.

Comment: it is a seperate call as you can't chain it to the conversion.

Comment: You can also pass the valueComparer as a third argument to HasConversion()

Answer (score 7):

From the [ValueComparer class documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.valuecomparer?view=efcore-3.1):

> Specifies custom value snapshotting and comparison for CLR types that
>   cannot be compared with Equals(Object, Object) and/or need a
>   deep/structural copy when taking a snapshot. For example, arrays of
>   primitive types will require both if mutation is to be detected.
>
> Snapshotting is the process of creating a copy of the value into a
>   snapshot so it can later be compared to determine if it has changed.
>   For some types, such as collections, this needs to be a deep copy of
>   the collection rather than just a shallow copy of the reference.

You can find more information on how to setup your ValueComparer on this issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17471

Answer (score 0):

In case you're here to find a ValueComparer for Dictionary<string,string>:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    //...

    ValueComparer<Dictionary<string, string>> stringDictionaryKeyValueComparer = new(
        (c1, c2) => c1.SequenceEqual(c2),
        c => c.Aggregate(0, (a, v) => HashCode.Combine(a, v.GetHashCode())),
        c => c.ToDictionary());

    //...

    builder.Entity<MyEntity>().Property(e => e.StringStringDictionary).HasConversion(
        v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
        v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(v),
        stringDictionaryKeyValueComparer);

    //...
}
```

Please note: This works for primitive types like int, string, etc. If you're using objects in the dictionary you need to replace `c => c.ToDictionary()` with code that creates a deep copy of your dictionary. See rdubois answer.